# Firefox keeps changing http://localnode:8080 to http://localnode.com8080/. How do I change this?

Tags: firefox, router, ham-radio

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. On version 11 it was doing this, but now it has changed. I am a ham radio operator and I am trying to use the wrt54g Linksys router for digital communications.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I think if I read correctly he taged firefox... hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define localnode as 127.0.0.1 in your DNS or in your hosts file (`/etc/hosts`).
Your browser is trying localnode.com because it can't find localnode. Or use `http://localhost:8080`